# How to convert HTML unsorted select list to HTML sort alphabetic select list

Tags: jquery, html, list, sorting

I have read many of the solutions proposed here. Most of the solutions explain how to sort the items in the list, but do not explain how to rebuild the list in alphabetical order and insert it instead of the old list, just the page is loaded. All in one.

Here my list:

```
<select id="ciudadseleccionada">
    <option value="madrid" data-url="http://cupon.local/app_dev.php/ciudad/cambiar-a-madrid">
        Madrid
    </option>
    <option value="barcelona" data-url="http://cupon.local/app_dev.php/ciudad/cambiar-a-barcelona">
        Barcelona
    </option>
    <option value="sevilla" data-url="http://cupon.local/app_dev.php/ciudad/cambiar-a-sevilla" selected="selected">
        Sevilla
    </option>
    <option value="valencia" data-url="http://cupon.local/app_dev.php/ciudad/cambiar-a-valencia">
        Valencia
    </option>
    <option value="zaragoza" data-url="http://cupon.local/app_dev.php/ciudad/cambiar-a-zaragoza">
        Zaragoza
    </option>
    <option value="malaga" data-url="http://cupon.local/app_dev.php/ciudad/cambiar-a-malaga">
        Málaga
    </option>
    <option value="murcia" data-url="http://cupon.local/app_dev.php/ciudad/cambiar-a-murcia">
        Murcia
    </option>
</select>
```

I need to sort the list above, in a new list in alphabetical order according to the "option value", and THEN insert the new sorted list in the SAME PLACE in the unsorted list.
How I can do this it with jQuery and / or java script? All in one.

**EDIT:** Here my complete HTML file, with the solution proposed by Rory and the suggestion of Billy (but not work):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>      
</head>
<body>
<select id="ciudadseleccionada">
    <option value="madrid" data-url="http://cupon.local/app_dev.php/ciudad/cambiar-a-madrid">
        Madrid
    </option>
    <option value="barcelona" data-url="http://cupon.local/app_dev.php/ciudad/cambiar-a-barcelona">
        Barcelona
    </option>
    <option value="sevilla" data-url="http://cupon.local/app_dev.php/ciudad/cambiar-a-sevilla" selected="selected">
        Sevilla
    </option>
    <option value="valencia" data-url="http://cupon.local/app_dev.php/ciudad/cambiar-a-valencia">
        Valencia
    </option>
    <option value="zaragoza" data-url="http://cupon.local/app_dev.php/ciudad/cambiar-a-zaragoza">
        Zaragoza
    </option>
    <option value="malaga" data-url="http://cupon.local/app_dev.php/ciudad/cambiar-a-malaga">
        Malaga
    </option>
    <option value="murcia" data-url="http://cupon.local/app_dev.php/ciudad/cambiar-a-murcia">
        Murcia
    </option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$( document ).ready(('#ciudadseleccionada option').sort(function(a, b) {
    var aVal = $(a).val(), bVal = $(b).val();
    return aVal < bVal ? -1 : aVal > bVal ? 1 : 0;
}).appendTo('#ciudadseleccionada'));
</script>      

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

To do this you need to implement your own `sort()` function logic which compares the `value` attributes of the `option` elements, then re-attaches them to their parent `select` in the correct order, something like this:

```
$('#ciudadseleccionada option').sort(function(a, b) {
    var aVal = $(a).val(), bVal = $(b).val();
    return aVal < bVal ? -1 : aVal > bVal ? 1 : 0;
}).appendTo('#ciudadseleccionada')
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/L0ndwm9p/)

Comment: Nice, although I don't love the nested / chained ternary.  That's a bit rough on the readability.

Comment: Rory thanks for the answer +1, I've been looking for something like this. One question I have is how does this work? Because isn't **"<"** and **">"** used in mathematics in JS? I mean **"$(a).val()"** and **"$(b).val()"** return strings and not integers, could you please help me understand how this works or possibly lead me to a link that does?

Comment: Rory: Thank you very much for your quick response, but when I copy and paste your function in my HTML file not work.  What can be the cause?

Comment: @ Jorge ,are you linking to jquery ?

Comment: try putting it in a jquery doc ready `$( document ).ready(function() {
   //    function stuff here ///
});`